# How to correctly run for loop, asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't seem to wrap my head around running async for loops.  Can someone please explain it in a simpler term so I can understand?

The result I get is the link opening 1 time.

(4) working

undefined

```
var v = 4;
for(i=0;i<v;i++){
    if(i < v){
    window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', 'test')
    console.log('working')
    }
    else
    {
    'done'
    }
}
```

I'm looking to get the page to open 5 times.

Comment: You clearly don't need the `if (i < v)` because the loop body won't execute if that's not true.

Comment: Also if you want it to open 5 times the loop limit should be 5, not 4.

Comment: Executing 4 or 5 times isn't important for my understanding.  Meaning the code I'm working on is similar, and I just don't understand why it only opens the popup 1 time.  I'm expecting 4-5 links.  5 if it's counting at 0.

Comment: What does "asynchronously" have to do with this?

Comment: Your loop as written will run 4 times. 0, 1, 2, and 3 are all less than 4, it stops at 4 because 4 isn't less than 4.

Comment: The window only opening once is likely a browser feature protecting the enduser from malicious/invasive code.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is why the webpage only opens once, I'm expecting it to open 4 times?

Comment: Ahh, Kevin, I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Basically I need my for loop to open the page, and I have a function that targets the open page by window.name, and retreive the DOM elements.  I think that would be the answer.  Not sure why I didn't think it could be Chrome preventing this.

I can solve this by doing it manually, I just wanted to pull all the elements at once from different pages.  Thank you all.

Comment: You can try adding a parameter with different values (even if not needed) to see if this gets around the browser only opening one new window.

Comment: @JasonOwens you cannot retrieve the contents of an opened page from a different domain.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, yea I'm just using that as an example.

Comment: @QuentinUK, actually, I just got it to work, but doing what you suggested, I used the 'i' variable as a part of the target name, and viola!  Thanks!  That did work!!!
 window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', 'test'+i,)